# What are the recommended requirements for running a node

Tags: node

There are a number of posts on here asking about slow synchronisation of a node. We see many answers stating the specifications of the node are not sufficient but nowhere have we got details of what the specifications should be and why.

An acceptable answer for this question should cover the below and ideally include some benchmarks showing time to synchronisation and other relevant metrics for different combinations of the below.

- Network speed
- IOPS
- Read/Write throughput
- Ram
- CPU Architecture/Speed

Comment: this question seems very wide, it's difficult to provide specific answers that will be other than listing an exhaustive list of configs from each people. Could you please try to reframe it to be a bit more narrow ? thanks!